# Translating a translated birth certificate

Tags: visas, uk, dual-nationality, translations

My child under 18 has a dual Austrian/Russian nationality and lives in Austria. I'm considering applying for a UK Standard Visitor Visa for them (as a Russian citizen) if it looks like they (as an Austrian citizen) can't travel to the UK visa-free shortly after Brexit.

I'm going to attach their translated birth certificate to the application, but I'm not sure how to go about translating this particular birth certificate, because it consists of:

Page 1: original in German (front), apostille (back)
Page 2: certified translation into Russian with the Russian Embassy's stamp re: Russian citizenship (front), Russian Embassy's stamps re: issued passports (back)
Page 3: a statement from the translator about the correctness of the Russian translation.

The three pages are bound together by the translator's stamp.

So the questions are:

1. what pages (or all of them?) should be translated into English for the UK visa center?
2. is it possible (advisible) to attach the English certified translation to the original of such a birth certificate (possibly damaging the Russian translator's stamp)?

Comment: Why do you think EU citizens won't be able to travel to the UK without a visa *shortly after Brexit*?

Comment: @HankyPanky there seems to be a lot of uncertainty around this issue at the moment. Since our trip in April is already paid for, I'd like to hedge my bets.

Comment: I think there is zero chance that post-Brexit there will be requirement for visa applications _in advance_. Surely the EU would at worst go into the same visa-free category as USA, Japan, etc.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus that would be great but such a regulation needs to be passed first, right? I'd love to talk odds but that would be a speculative question that can't be asked here...

Comment: The British have announced that the only difference from today is a passport will be required. The National ID will no longer suffice. I can not imagine why you want to go to the time and expense of obtaining visas as Russian nationals. The likelihood they will be denied for some reason must be vastly greater than the possibility the UK will suddenly require advance visas for Austrians, after saying they shall not. https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/brexit-european-union-eu-passport-visa-rules-strasbourg-travel-permit-etas-a8631916.html

Comment: @AndrewLazarus oh, sounds great, that's my two Austrians covered, then! Thanks for the link! If you have heard anything re: EEA family permit scheme, I'd greatly appreciate that information too. (And somebody will hopefully move that discussion to a chat since a regular user can't seem to do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a local agency that specializes in authorized translations into English:

> what pages (or all of them?) should be translated into English for the UK visa center?

In addition to translating the original, it is *possible* to translate relevant parts from other attached translations (like the stamp confirming the Russian citizenship in our case). The final decision on what is *necessary* for UKVI is at the applicant's discretion.

> is it possible (advisible) to attach the English certified translation to the original of such a birth certificate (possibly damaging the Russian translator's stamp)?

It is possible to attach a new translation to the existing bundle using a different corner of the original.